# How to Send List<string> images to string images with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have some data in my Model and Images in Model. Images that are coming From Database and I want to add that image in my Shopping Cart with jquery on click button. I am getting all the data except Images here is the code. Model. Images are the List of string Images and I want one image only in my string images cart class. Help it out.

```html
@{
@model MobileModel
}
<button type="submit" class="addcartbtn mt-5" data-pid="@Model.Id" data-pname="@Model.Name" data-pprice="@Model.Price" data-purl="@Model.Images" data-pqty="1">
    <span class=" fa fa-shopping-cart"> Add To Cart</span>
</button>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(".addcartbtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var obj = {
        "Id": $(this).data("pid"),
        "Name": $(this).data("pname"),
        "Price": $(this).data("pprice"),
        "Images": $(this).data("purl"),
        "Quantity": $(this).data("pqty")
    }
    $(this).parents("#proditem").fadeOut(300);
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/Cart/Add",
            type: "GET",
            data:  obj
        }
    ).done(function (itemscount) {
        $("#cartitems").text(itemscount);
});
```

**Cart Class**

```cs
public class ShoppingCartItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Images { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get {return Quantity * Price;}}
}
```

**Cart Controller where i want to send data**

```cs
 public class CartController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public int Add(ShoppingCartItem item)
        {
            ShoppingCart cart = HttpContext.Session.Get<ShoppingCart>(WebUtil.Cart);
            if (cart == null) cart = new ShoppingCart();
            cart.Add(item);
            HttpContext.Session.Set(WebUtil.Cart, cart);            
            return cart.NumberOfItems;
        }
```

**MobileModel class form where data is comming**

```cs
 public class MobileModel
    {
        public MobileModel()
        {
            Images = new List<string>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Price  { get; set; }
        public List<string> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What is the problem you are facing? What is preventing you?

Comment: What's the type of @Model.Id,@Model.Name,etc? Can you give us your codes in code behind and more detailed view codes？

Comment: @YongqingYu Check Now..

Comment: @Ahmad i am unable to send image to controller.

Answer (score 0):

In ShoppingCartItem Model class change

```
public string Images { get; set; }
```

variable to

```
public List<string> Images { get; set; }
```

then in your razor view file get the image like this

```
@Model.Images[0]
```

Comment: i know this but to send this Model.Images[0] to controller its not working with this. @ShoaibRaza

Comment: and i don't want to change string with list of string tell me the solution with thiese classes.

Answer (score 0):

It will not save the list of images if you directly pass List data to the button's attribute, you can `change them to a string by comma to split`.

```
<button type="submit" class="addcartbtn mt-5" data-pid="@Model.Id" data-pname="@Model.Name" data-pprice="@Model.Price" 
data-purl="@String.Join(",", Model.Images)"  data-pqty="1">
    <span class=" fa fa-shopping-cart"> Add To Cart</span>
</button>


  <script>
        $(".addcartbtn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var obj = {
                "Id": $(this).data("pid"),
                "Name": $(this).data("pname"),
                "Price": $(this).data("pprice"),
                "Images": $(this).data("purl").split(',')[0],
                "Quantity": $(this).data("pqty")
            }
            ...
        });
    </script>
```

Or you can use `ViewBag` to pass this List of images:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        MobileModel mobileModel = new MobileModel()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "aaaa",
            Price = 200,
            Images = new List<string>(){ "Image1","Image2","Image3"}
        };
        ViewBag.Images = mobileModel.Images;
        return View(mobileModel);
    } 


$(".addcartbtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = {
        "Id": $(this).data("pid"),
        "Name": $(this).data("pname"),
        "Price": $(this).data("pprice"), 
        "Images": "@ViewBag.Images[0]",
        "Quantity": $(this).data("pqty")
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: i am getting Model.Images on id based if i will use ViewBag it will send all the images available in database and i need specific item in shoping cart..

Yes i need something like that string comma split thing but with your code its sending null in the images in controller. :(

Comment: @AliRazali，I suggest you edit your question, describing your needs in detail. And what's the relationship between these two classes? How do you get images based on the id? If your Modal.Images is empty, then you did get null in ajax. please make sure that Images come from controller have data, you can use F12 to debug js code to confirm this issue.

Comment: i am very sure about data just before sending the Mode.Images i am also showing these images and other data like Model.price Model.name i am getting those in controller but only in images it giving me null.